# webRTC Live streaming Nativescript

Tags: webrtc, nativescript, nativescript-angular

I need to create a broadcast video from the server to many clients

In server i use https://airensoft.gitbook.io/ovenmediaengine/

When connecting for the web, I use

```
"file": "ws://3.123.0.22:3333/app/test_o",
"type": "webrtc"
```

please tell me
how to implement the same thing on nativescript

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for posting a question about OvenMediaEngine.
First of all, we've never used NativeScript, so it's difficult to give an accurate guide, but I'll let you know what we understand as much as possible.

**1.**
The easiest way to play WebRTC with NativeScript is by adding a WebView and playing it inside.
Please refer to [this page (click)](https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/components/web-view), add a WebView to your project, then create a page that can load [OvenPlayer](https://github.com/airensoft/ovenplayer) in that WebView.

**2.**
Another way is to install a plugin. Click [HERE](https://market.nativescript.org/plugins/nativescript-webrtc-plugin) to install this plugin on your project and connect the OvneMediaEegine Signalling to be able to stream with WebRTC.
Please see to [our guide (click)](https://airensoft.gitbook.io/ovenmediaengine/streaming/webrtc-publishing#signalling-protocol), interlock Signalling with WebSocket, get the SDP of OvenMediaEngine, and put it in WebRTC plugin.

Thank you!